# Is there a FetchAPI equivalent to a GET form submission?

Tags: forms, oauth, fetch-api

I have a form like this

```
<form action="https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize" method="GET" id="authForm">
   <input name="redirect_uri" value="[my-redirect-uri]"/>
   <input name="client_id" value="[my-client-id]"/>
   <input name="response_type" value="code"/>
   <input name="scope" value="activity:read_all"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

This works exactly as needed but I don't want it to be a form so I figured `fetch` was a better solution to simply submit a manually constructed request.

So I blindly tried the following but get a CORS error.

```
fetch("https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=[my-redirect-uri]&client_id=[my-client-id]&response_type=code&scope=activity:read_all",
   {
      method: 'GET'
   })
```

Is fetch the right way to do this?
What is the difference between the form submission that works and the fetch request that doesn't?
How can I structure/encode my fetch request so that it works as the form does?

Thanks all